# Testing image validation in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I wrote a controller that tests if an image is valid, as in does it actually contain an image or is just a 1000 pixel square of nothing. It takes an image through a URL. It works fine but I can't figure out how to write this unit test for the life of me. How would I mock a URL with image data? I have been digging around and can't find an answer.

Comment: Something like new File(path).toURI().toURL()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local file can be represented by a URL using the scheme `file://` .So just save a test image locally accessible to your unit test

ref:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme